# Modificar un String

Tags: java, string

Tengo que pedir al usuario una cadena de la cual de cada palabra tiene que poner la primera letra de cada palabra al final y esta acompañada de un ai. Por ejemplo el usuario introduce: `La casa azul` y quedaria como `alai asacai zulaai`.
Ya he conseguido sacar el introducir el ai al final de cada palabra pero no logro conseguir cambiar la primera letra de cada palabra de posición.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String frase="";
    String aux="";
    System.out.println("Introduce una frase ");
    frase=sc.nextLine();

    String [] espai= frase.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<espai.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(espai[i].concat("ai")+" "); 
        aux=espai[i];


    }   

}
```

Comment: ¿La primera palabra (`La`) no debería quedar como `aLai`?

Comment: correcto ahora lo corrijo gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ver si lo he entendido bien. Obviando la parte en la que pides la frase, podrías hacer algo así:

```
String [] espai= frase.split(" ");
String cadenafinal = "";
for(int i = 0; i < espai.length; i++) {

    String aux = "" + espai[i].charAt( espai[i].length() - 1);
    aux += espai[ i].substring( 0, espai[i].length() - 1) + "ai";

    System.out.println( aux);
    cadenafinal += aux + " ";

}
```

En cada vuelta del bucle te imprimirá cada palabra con la última letra puesta en primera posición y concatenando al final los caracteres *ai*. Y te guardará en `cadenafinal` la cadena modificada.

**Segunda versión:**

Vale. Después de tus comentarios a mi respuesta, ahora he entendido lo que querías. Esto lo hace más fácil aún. En este caso,  quedaría así:

```
String [] espai= frase.split(" ");
String cadenafinal = "";
for(int i = 0; i < espai.length; i++) {

    String aux = espai[ i].substring( 1) + espai[i].charAt( 0) + "ai";

    System.out.println( aux);
    cadenafinal += aux + " ";

}
```

En cada vuelta del bucle trata una palabra de tu frase. Primero se queda con todos los caracteres de la palabra menos el primero, a eso le añade el primero, y a todo le añade "ai".

Comment: Es el primer digito de la cadena que va al final concatenado de AI no el ultimo al principio.

Comment: Tenía mis dudas de haberlo entendido...

Comment: La idea es la que has puesto solo que en tu caso obviando el +ai pones el ultimo digito al principio y yo tengo que poner el primero al final y a eso sumarle el +"ai"

Comment: Una pregunta porque solo substring de (1) y no de 1 hasta el final de esa string ,la parte de concatenar con espai de i del caracter 0 lo entiendo pero eso no.

Comment: @winnie Como te ha comentado MiguelM27 en otro comentario es por que hay 2 `substring`, los puedes ver en la clase String [método substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Comment: Revisa la documentación de la función `substring`. Puedes llamarla con un solo parámetro y lo que indica es el índice del primer `char` a partir del que hacer el `substing`, y al no incluir el segundo parámetro, se asume que es hasta el final de la cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto funciona para lo que pides

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String frase="";
    String aux="";
    System.out.println("Introduce una frase ");
    frase=sc.nextLine();

    String[] espai = frase.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<espai.length;i++) {
        char caract = espai[i].charAt(0);
        espai[i]=espai[i].substring(1)+caract;
        System.out.print(espai[i].concat("ai")+" "); 
        aux=espai[i];


    }   

}
```

Comment: Correcto esta si funciona con lo que yo quería. Lo que no entiendo es lo 
 de espai[i]=espai[i].substring(1)+caract; El substring no devuelve de una parte a otra es decir tu le pones un 1 pero no deberia ser de 1 hasta el final de esa palabra?

Comment: Hay dos métodos substring. Uno con índice inicial y final y otro solo con índice inicial que devuelve hasta el final de la cadena.